# Mapping readonly child collection with AutoMapper

Tags: collections, automapper

It's not so much a question, as I have found a way to do what I want, but it seems like there should be a better way to do it. I've searched everywhere and not found anything.

Basically, I have what I consider a very standard object model.

```
public class Parent
{
    private readonly IList<Child> _children = new List<Child>();
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get { return _children; } }
    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Child
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

*(I've omitted properties irrelevant to the problem and error checking and guarding for the sake of clarity...)*

```
public class ParentDTO
{
    List<ChildDTO> Children = new List<ChildDTO>();
}
```

and

```
public class ChildDTO
{
}
```

The reason I'm using a method to add children to the collection is to maintain control of business logic that needs to be processed when a child is added.

With the standard mapping of:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDTO, Parent>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, ChildDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ChildDTO, Child>();
```

It seems to work fine coming from the service layer. The children of the domain object map perfectly to the list of `ChildDTO` instances.

However, when mapping back the other way, the collection on the domain model isn't set - because it's readonly, obviously. There doesn't appear to be any way to directly set the private field using AutoMapper. I have tried various suggestions found on here, and other parts of the internet.

In the end, I came up with the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDTO, Parent>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Children, o => o.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((s, d) =>
                        {
                            foreach(var c in s.Children)
                                d.AddChild(Mapper.Map<ChildDTO, Child>(c));
                        });
```

This works as I required. However, I can't help feeling that there has to be a better way, and I haven't tested this with an existing parent that's had children modified and maybe added and removed, so I know it's not actually correct yet. Ultimately, this domain model is persisted using NHibernate, so I do have to worry about that. But, one thing at a time. :)

Hopefully this might help someone else who's encountering the same problem, and maybe someone who's solved it properly will be able to correct me.

Comment: +1 your aftermap solution saved me.

Comment: Cool solution. I'll borrow it :-)

Comment: Great idea with AfterMap. It's so much easier to work with Source and Destination objects than with ResolutionResult and stuff like that!

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to have logic inside property getter or setter, but what about adding setter to Children property of Parent class

```
public class Parent
{
    private readonly IList<Child> _children = new List<Child>();

    public IEnumerable<Child> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set => AddChildren(value);
    }

    public void AddChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(child);
    }

    private void AddChildren(IEnumerable<Child> children)
    {
        _children.Clear();

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            AddChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

And AfterMap logic is not more necessary. Mapping configuration will be simple

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDTO, Parent>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are going to protect properties for good business logic reasons then it would be bad if AutoMapper circumvented them when doing its mapping. In situations like this I prefer to abandon the fluent syntax and place the creation logic in its own method like this:

```
private Parent MapParentDTOToParent(ParentDTO source)
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    // Business logic here
    return parent
}
```

and then:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentDTO, Parent>().ConvertUsing(MapParentDTOToParent);
```

I find this easier to follow than having lots of ignore declarations.